# error passing 'const' as 'this' argument in c++ with ide qt

Tags: c++, qt

I am developing an application in `C++` with `Qt`  , i have a class : `AnimationMasse`

```
class AnimationMasse
{
public:
        int etat ;
        double x ;
        double y ;
public:
        AnimationMasse();
        void setx(double XX);
};

AnimationMasse::AnimationMasse()
{
        etat =  0 ;
        x    = -0.54 ;
        y    = -0.2 ;
}


void AnimationMasse::setx(double XX){

    x = x+XX;
}
```

i'm created an objet :

```
QVector <AnimationMasse> Masse;
AnimationMasse x ;
Masse.append(x) ;
```

The problem is : if i do :

```
   ui->animation->Masse.at(0).setx(1);
```

seems to me , error :

> error: passing 'const AnimationMasse' as 'this' argument of 'void
>   AnimationMasse::setx(double)' discards qualifiers [-fpermissive]
>
> ui->animation->Masse.at(0).setx(1);

who solved this problem ?

Comment: The compiler error message clearly indicates that you have a `const` object somewhere. The code snippets you provided so far have no `const` at all. Provide *real* code, not made up sketches.

Comment: Apparently `Masse` is declared as `const`.

Comment: i'm edditing the code , i'm create the real code .

Comment: [`const T & QVector::at(int i) const`](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qvector.html#at). There's your const.

Comment: @user4581301 how  solved this problem ?

Comment: @BkarimCe use the operator [](int i) version which has an overload to return a non-const reference to an element, like,
    ui->animation->Masse[0].setx(1);

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to use QVector at or operator\[\] to get a pointer to the element](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10665162/how-to-use-qvector-at-or-operator-to-get-a-pointer-to-the-element)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

As you see in Qt documentation http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qvector.html#at function `at` return const refernce, so you can not call `setx(1)`. You can use in this case operator[] of `QVector` class:

```
T & operator[](int i)
```

Simple example:

```
#include "QCoreApplication"
#include "QVector"
#include "QtDebug"

class AnimationMasse
{
private:
        int etat ;
        double x ;
        double y ;
public:
        AnimationMasse()
            : etat(0)
            , x(-0.54)
            , y(-0.2)
        {
        }

        double getx(){return x;}
        void setx(double XX){ x += XX; }
};

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    QCoreApplication a(argc, argv);

    QVector <AnimationMasse> Masse;
    AnimationMasse x;
    Masse.append(x);

    qDebug() << Masse[0].getx();
    Masse[0].setx(1);
    qDebug() << Masse[0].getx();

    return a.exec();
}
```

Comment: Replace ui->animation->Masse.at(0).setx(1) on ui->animation->Masse[0].setx(1)

Comment: @BkarimCe it sounds like you aren't aware of what `const` is. It was probably derived from constant, but has grown from just being constant data to mean data you cannot change. It might be constant, but it might just be data with a restriction on it to prevent accidental damage. That means calling something like `setx` to change the data is rejected by the compiler. To get around this, you need to use [an accessor like `operator[]`](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qvector.html#operator-5b-5d) that does not return a `const` reference.

Comment: @user4581301 give me an example how user operator[] of QVector

Comment: @KirillChernikov did exactly that three comments up: `ui->animation->Masse[0].setx(1)`.

Answer (score 3):

```
ui->animation->Masse.at(missajour).setx(1);
```

`Masse` seems to be a `vector`, and currently it is a `const` object and hence returing a `const_reference`. Then the expression on left of `setx` becomes a `const AnimationMasse`. Therefore, you cannot call `setx`.

The objects `ui`, `animation` and `Masse` all have to be non-const at the call location.

Comment: The vector Masse is not constant

Comment: I guess you are not paying attention. I agree `Masse` may not be const, but `animation` may be, or `ui` may be. Or the method in which `ui` is a class-member may be a `const` function.

Comment: @BkarimCe The vector isn't, but the `QVector::at` is a bit different from `vector::at` and returns a `const` reference. So Ajay's mostly right, just operating from incomplete information.